# Android add underline dynamically

Tags: android

I watn to dynamically add and remove unerline for a TextView in my application.

Firstly I am adding underline in onCreateView of a fragment with using of AQuery:
   `aQuery.id(R.id.tv_help_consult).getTextView().setPaintFlags(aq.id(R.id.tv_help_consult).getTextView().getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)`;

And it looks fine.
[image]

But when I am removing underline (and adding again) something is happening to the font so you can see pixels:

[image]

I am using these methods in a clickListenner to change the underline:

```
private void headingFontHighlightOn(TextView heading) {
        //        removing underline
        heading.setPaintFlags(0);
        //        changing color
        heading.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.orange));
    }


private void headingFontHighlightOff(TextView heading) {
         //        making underline
         heading.setPaintFlags(heading.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
         //        changing color
         heading.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.black));
        }
```

Of course, I can use alternative String resource with `<u>` tags and just change the string resource.
But I want to firure out what is happenning here

**EDIT:** in case somebody needs,
My final solution is based on **Chintan Bawa**'s answer.
I just modified methods to be independent from String resources (while using on different TextViews):

```
private void headingFontHighlightOn(TextView heading) {
        //        removing underline
        heading.setText(heading.getText().toString());
        //        changing color
        heading.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.orange));
    }

    private void headingFontHighlightOff(TextView heading) {
        //        making underline
        String underlinedText = "<u>" + heading.getText() + "</u>";
        heading.setText(Html.fromHtml(underlinedText));

        //        changing color
        heading.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.black));
    }
```

Also I removed all paint flags.

Comment: One simple solution would use two strings for text , one with undeline and one without it

Comment: Yeah, I am having this solution on my mind. But what is wrong wih this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to **underline** text in `TextView`

```
heading.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Legal assistance</u>"));
```

and to remove **underline** from text in `TextView`

```
heading.setText("Legal assistance"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clickable span if you want that underline should be clickable.If not just ignore onclick operations.You can use below code to have underline how you like

String str = "You have " + sessionUserId.getfudiyoPointsSession()
                    + " fudiyo points available. What are fudiyo points?";

```
        int index = str.indexOf(".");
        TextView txtfudiyo_point = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_fudiyo_point);

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(str);
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                try {
                    showTermsConditions();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ErrorEmail.sendEmail(UserHomeScreen.this, e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setColor(Color.RED);
                ds.setUnderlineText(true);
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, index + 2, ss.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        txtfudiyo_point.setText(ss);
        txtfudiyo_point.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thank you. But it seemes too complicated in my case